# How to print out of list from zip() vertically in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a set of data that I mapped with zip(). I'm writing it to csv, but it's all on the first row. I'd like have each set of data in () to be in a separate row (listed vertically) for easier readability.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
from scipy import arange
import csv
import math

df=pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\20amps.csv')
N=df.shape[0] #Number of samples
T=125000 #Frequency of Signal
k=arange(N)
Ts=N/T
freq=k/Ts
freq=freq[range(N//40)]

amp=df["AC1 A"]
rms= [i * math.sqrt(2) for i in amp]
yf=fft(rms)/N
yf=yf[range(N//40)]

zipped = zip (freq, abs(yf))
w = list(zipped)
print(w)

#Writing to csv file
with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvFile: 
    writer =csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(w)
```

Here's the output/csv
[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8y2H.png)
[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt84A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
w = list(zipped)
print(w)
```

Do:

```
w = list(zipped)
for item in w:
    print(item)
```

Also, instead of:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvFile: 
    writer =csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(w)
```

You probably want:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvFile: 
    writer =csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for item in w:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fast way -  change your `print(w)` to `print('\n'.join([str(s) for s in w]))` and change `writer.writerow(w)` to `for` loop:

```
for s in w:
    writer.writerow(s)
```